# Combine lists to the least possible amount of 2-dimensional lists

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Sorry for the bad description in the title.

Consider a 2-dimensional list such as this:

```
list = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4]
]
```

If I were to extract all possible "vertical" combinations of this list, for a total of 2*2*2=8 combinations, they would be the following sequences:

```
1, 2, 3
2, 2, 3
1, 3, 3
2, 3, 3
1, 2, 4
2, 2, 4
1, 3, 4
2, 3, 4
```

Now, let's say I remove some of these sequences. Let's say I only want to keep sequences which have either the number 2 in position #1 OR number 4 in position #3. Then I would be left with these sequences:

```
2, 2, 3
2, 3, 3
1, 2, 4
2, 2, 4
1, 3, 4
2, 3, 4
```

### The problem

I would like to re-combine these remaining sequences to the least possible amount of 2-dimensional lists needed to contain all sequences but no less or no more.

By doing so, the resulting 2-dimensional lists in this particular example would be:

```
list_1 = [
    [2],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 4]
]
list_2 = [
    [1],
    [2, 3],
    [4] 
]
```

In this particular case, the resulting lists can be thought out. But how would I go about if there were thousands of sequences yielding hundereds of 2-dimensional lists? I have been trying to come up with a good algorithm for two weeks now, but I am getting nowhere near a satisfying result.

Comment: What's your current algorithm and what are you unhappy about?

Comment: The algorithms I came up with were all spaghetti-like. And while indeed producing a number of 2-dimensional lists from a set of sequences, they were not producing the least possible amount of them.

Answer (score 0):

Divide et impera, or divide and conquer. If we have a logical expression, stating that the value at position x should be a or the value at position y should be b, then we have 3 cases:

1. a is the value at position x and b is the value at position y
2. a is the value at position x and b is not the value at position y
3. a is not the value at position x and b is the value at position y

So, first you generate all your scenarios, you know now that you have 3 scenarios.

Then, you effectively separate your cases and handle all of them in a sub-routine as they were your main tasks. The philosophy behind divide et imera is to reduce your complex problem into several similar, but less complex problems, until you reach triviality.

Comment: This is not my problem. My problem is the combination of a given number of sequences into lists, regardless of what sequences I had from the beginning or what measures i took to filter out certain sequences.